# select que depende otro select js

Tags: javascript

buenas estoy tratando de hacer un select que depende otro select con js puro , pero no me sale.

este es mi código html :

```
 <table>
        <tr>
           <td align=right>Carreras:</td>
           <td align=left colspan=3>
               <select name="carrera" id="carrera" onchange="cargarMaterias();">
                   <option value="">Seleccione una Carrera...</option>
               </select>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>                    
           <td align=right>Materia:</td>
           <td align=left colspan=3>
               <select name="materia" id="materia">
                   <option value="">Seleccione una Materia...</option>
               </select>
           </td>
       </tr>
     </table>


este es mi codigo en js :

function cargarCarreras(){
    var array = ["Sistemas", "Redes", "Electrica", "Industrial", "Electronica"];
    array.sort();
    addOptions("carrera", array);
}



function addOptions(domElement, array) {
    var selector = document.getElementsByName(domElement)[0];
    for (carrera in array) {
        var opcion = document.createElement("option");
        opcion.text = array[carrera];
        opcion.value = array[carrera].toLowerCase()
        selector.add(opcion);
    }
}


function cargarMaterias(){
    var listaMaterias = {
      Sistemas: ["Base de Datos", "Analisis de Sistemas I", "Redes Inalambricas", "Inteligtencia Artificial", "Ingenieria de Software"],
      Redes: ["Analisis de Señales", "Redes II", "Seguridad de la Informacion", "Calculo III", "Electricidad y Magnetismo"],
      Electrica: ["Fisica II", "Termodinamica", "Resistencia de Materiales", "Electronica Analogica I", "Ecuaciones Diferenciales"],
      Industrial: ["Fundamentos de Marketing", "Investigacion Operativa", "Estudio de Materiales", "Quimica Organica", "Ecuaciones Diferenciales"],
      Electronica: ["Circuitos Electricos", "Electronica Analogica II", "Fisica II", "Electronica Digital", "Analisis de Señales"]
    }
    var carreras = document.getElementById('carrera')
    var materias = document.getElementById('materia')
    var carreraSeleccionada = carreras.value

    materias.innerHTML = '<option value="">Seleccione una Materia...</option>'

    if(carreraSeleccionada !== ''){
      carreraSeleccionada = listaMaterias[carreraSeleccionada]
      carreraSeleccionada.sort()

        carreraSeleccionada.forEach(function(materia){
        let opcion = document.createElement('option')
        opcion.value = materia
        opcion.text = materia
        materias.add(opcion)
      });
    }

  }

cargarCarreras();
```

apreciaría mucho de su ayuda , de antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respetando lo que tenés hecho, te comparto con las correcciones necesarias.

El inconveniente era que tu `array` de `listaMaterias` decía **"Sistemas"** con inicial mayúscula y tu `value` del `select` era **"sistemas"** con inicial minúsculas.

```js
        function cargarCarreras() {
            var array = ["Sistemas", "Redes", "Electrica", "Industrial", "Electronica"];
            array.sort();
            addOptions("carrera", array);
        }
    
        function addOptions(domElement, array) {
            var selector = document.getElementsByName(domElement)[0];
            for (carrera in array) {
                var opcion = document.createElement("option");
                opcion.text = array[carrera];
                opcion.value = array[carrera].toLowerCase()
                selector.add(opcion);
            }
        }
    
        function cargarMaterias() {
    
            // Modifique los nombres de tus propiedas a minúsculas.
            var listaMaterias = {
                sistemas: ["Base de Datos", "Analisis de Sistemas I", "Redes Inalambricas", "Inteligtencia Artificial", "Ingenieria de Software"],
                redes: ["Analisis de Señales", "Redes II", "Seguridad de la Informacion", "Calculo III", "Electricidad y Magnetismo"],
                electrica: ["Fisica II", "Termodinamica", "Resistencia de Materiales", "Electronica Analogica I", "Ecuaciones Diferenciales"],
                industrial: ["Fundamentos de Marketing", "Investigacion Operativa", "Estudio de Materiales", "Quimica Organica", "Ecuaciones Diferenciales"],
                electronica: ["Circuitos Electricos", "Electronica Analogica II", "Fisica II", "Electronica Digital", "Analisis de Señales"]
            }
            var carreras = document.getElementById('carrera')
            var materias = document.getElementById('materia')
            // La carrera seleccionada se convierte a minúsuculas para que podás buscarla tal cual en tu array de listaMaterias
            var carreraSeleccionada = carreras.value.toLowerCase()
    
            materias.innerHTML = '<option value="">Seleccione una Materia...</option>'
    
            if (carreraSeleccionada !== '') {
                // sistemas que es lo que seleccionaste, si es igual a sistemas en tu array listaMaterias
                carreraSeleccionada = listaMaterias[carreraSeleccionada]
                // Validamos que traiga el listado de materias, ya que sino te dará un error que no existe el método sort, porque no es un array sino un texto
                if (!!carreraSeleccionada.length) carreraSeleccionada.sort()
    
                carreraSeleccionada.forEach(function (materia) {
                    let opcion = document.createElement('option')
                    opcion.value = materia
                    opcion.text = materia
                    materias.add(opcion)
                });
            }
    
        }
    
        cargarCarreras();
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Carreras:</td>
    <td colspan=3>
      <select name="carrera" id="carrera" onchange="cargarMaterias();">
        <option value="">Seleccione una Carrera...</option>
      </select>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Materia:</td>
    <td colspan=3>
      <select name="materia" id="materia">
        <option value="">Seleccione una Materia...</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```